# Get column from first and last entry of grouping in Snowflake query

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to run a query which gets the OHLC statistics from stock trades. To do this, I've created the following query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(T.size), 
    SUM(T.size) / SUM(T.price), 
    FIRST_VALUE(T.price), 
    LAST_VALUE(T.price),
    MAX(T.price),
    MIN(T.price),
    FLOOR(T.sip_timestamp / 3600000000000)
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM trades AS T
    WHERE 
        T.symbol = 'NTAP' AND 
        T.sip_timestamp >= 1640995200000000000 AND
        T.sip_timestamp < 1672531200000000000
    ORDER BY T.sip_timestamp) AS T
GROUP BY FLOOR(T.sip_timestamp / 3600000000000)
```

This is supposed to work by filtering the trades data to a timestamp window, grouping it by a time bucket (equal to one hour) and then calculating the statistics based on this. The volume, weighted value, high, low and opening time values are easy but I'm having trouble generating the open and closing prices. I'm using the `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` windowed functions but I'm not sure how to make these work in a grouping context. Does anyone know how to get the proper result here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [FIRST_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html) and LAST_VALUE are a window frame functions not [aggregate functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-aggregation.html), thus do not operate in the domain of a GROUP BY

So what you want to do is define the scope of the FIRST_VALUE via a partition and order by clause, and then in the GROUP BY use an [ANY_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/any_value.html)

thus:

```
with trades(symbol, sip_timestamp, size, price) as (
    select * from values
        ('NTAP', 1640995200000000000, 100, 1.234),
        ('NTAP', 1640995200000000001, 100, 1.111)
)
SELECT 
    bucket,
    SUM(T.size), 
    SUM(T.size) / SUM(T.price), 
    ANY_VALUE(b_fv) as bucket_first_value, 
    ANY_VALUE(b_lv) as bucket_last_value, 
    MAX(T.price) as max_price,
    MIN(T.price) as min_price
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,FLOOR(T.sip_timestamp / 3600000000000) as bucket
        ,FIRST_VALUE(T.price) over (partition by bucket order by T.sip_timestamp) as b_fv
        ,LAST_VALUE(T.price) over (partition by bucket order by T.sip_timestamp) as b_lv 
    FROM trades AS T
    WHERE 
        T.symbol = 'NTAP' AND 
        T.sip_timestamp >= 1640995200000000000 AND
        T.sip_timestamp < 1672531200000000000
    ) AS T
GROUP BY bucket
```

now given you had a sub-select I put the FIRST_VALUES/LAST_VALUE there as nested window function don't play nice together.

I also put the `bucket` in that layer also.

| BUCKET | SUM(T.SIZE) | SUM(T.SIZE) / SUM(T.PRICE) | BUCKET_FIRST_VALUE | BUCKET_LAST_VALUE | MAX_PRICE | MIN_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 455,832 | 200 | 85.287846 | 1.234 | 1.111 | 1.234 | 1.111 |

if you have many values you can use ROW_NUMBER and IFF to have a single value, and then use a MAX, so this gives the same results:

```
SELECT 
    bucket,
    SUM(T.size), 
    SUM(T.size) / SUM(T.price), 
    max(b_fv) as bucket_first_value, 
    max(b_lv) as bucket_last_value, 
    MAX(T.price) as max_price,
    MIN(T.price) as min_price
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,FLOOR(T.sip_timestamp / 3600000000000) as bucket
        ,IFF(row_number() over (partition by bucket order by T.sip_timestamp) = 1 , T.price, null) as b_fv
        ,IFF(row_number() over (partition by bucket order by T.sip_timestamp desc) = 1 , T.price, null) as b_lv 
    FROM trades AS T
    WHERE 
        T.symbol = 'NTAP' AND 
        T.sip_timestamp >= 1640995200000000000 AND
        T.sip_timestamp < 1672531200000000000
    ) AS T
GROUP BY bucket
```

now if you have many things you want with the same order you can split those apart like:

```
SELECT 
    bucket,
    SUM(T.size), 
    SUM(T.size) / SUM(T.price), 
    max(b_fv) as bucket_first_value, 
    max(b_lv) as bucket_last_value, 
    max(b_fv_2) as bucket_first_value_2, 
    max(b_lv_2) as bucket_last_value_2, 
    MAX(T.price) as max_price,
    MIN(T.price) as min_price
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,FLOOR(T.sip_timestamp / 3600000000000) as bucket
        ,row_number() over (partition by bucket order by T.sip_timestamp) as rw_f
        ,row_number() over (partition by bucket order by T.sip_timestamp desc) as rw_d
        ,IFF(rw_f = 1 , T.price, null) as b_fv
        ,IFF(rw_f = 1 , T.price, null) as b_fv_2
        ,IFF(rw_d = 1 , T.price, null) as b_lv 
        ,IFF(rw_d = 1 , T.price, null) as b_lv_2
    FROM trades AS T
    WHERE 
        T.symbol = 'NTAP' AND 
        T.sip_timestamp >= 1640995200000000000 AND
        T.sip_timestamp < 1672531200000000000
    ) AS T
GROUP BY bucket
```

### Aggregating Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WindowAggregator(bucket string, bucket_time float, size float, price float)
    RETURNS TABLE (bucket string, sum float, avg float, first float, last float, max float, min float)
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS '{
            initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
               this.ccount = 0;
               this.size_sum = 0;
               this.price_sum = 0;
               this.price_min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
               this.price_max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
               this.price_sum = 0;
               this.last_key = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
               this.last_val = 0;
               this.first_key = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
               this.first_val = 0;
            },
            processRow: function get_params(row, rowWriter, context){
                    this.bucket = row.BUCKET;
                    if(row.PRICE < this.price_min ) { 
                        this.price_min = row.PRICE; 
                    }
                    if(row.PRICE > this.price_max ) { 
                        this.price_max = row.PRICE; 
                    }
                    if(row.PRICE < this.price_min ) { 
                        this.price_min = row.PRICE; 
                    }
                    if(row.BUCKET_TIME > this.last_key ) { 
                        this.last_key = row.BUCKET_TIME; 
                        this.last_val = row.PRICE; 
                    }
                    if(row.BUCKET_TIME < this.first_key ) { 
                        this.first_key = row.BUCKET_TIME;
                        this.first_val = row.PRICE;
                    }
                    this.price_sum += row.PRICE;
                    this.size_sum += row.SIZE;
            },
            finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {
                rowWriter.writeRow({
                    BUCKET: this.bucket, 
                    SUM: this.size_sum, 
                    AVG: this.size_sum/this.price_sum, 
                    FIRST: this.first_val, 
                    LAST: this.last_val, 
                    MAX: this.price_max, 
                    MIN: this.price_min});
            },
        }';
```

```
with trades(symbol, sip_timestamp, size, price) as (
    select * from values
        ('NTAP', 1640995200000000000, 100, 1.234),
        ('NTAP', 1640995200000000001, 10, 77.7),
        ('NTAP', 1640995200000000002, 100, 1.111)
)
SELECT 
    wa.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,FLOOR(T.sip_timestamp / 3600000000000) as bucket
        ,(T.sip_timestamp % 3600000000000)::float as bucket_time
    FROM trades AS T
    WHERE 
        T.symbol = 'NTAP' AND 
        T.sip_timestamp >= 1640995200000000000 AND
        T.sip_timestamp < 1672531200000000000
    ) AS T
cross join TABLE(WindowAggregator(t.bucket::text, T.bucket_time, T.size::float, T.price::float) over (partition by t.bucket)) as wa;
```

gives:

| BUCKET | SUM | AVG | FIRST | LAST | MAX | MIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 455832 | 210 | 2.623524268 | 1.234 | 1.111 | 77.7 | 1.111 |

Comment: Wow, I hadn't considered doing it that way. Excellent solution!

Comment: How would these solutions compare to creating an aggregate function?

Comment: I am perplexed by what you mean by "creating an aggregate function" the database provides the functions and we just "use them". There is not a aggregate function that over the aggregate function allows custom order, because aggregation is implicitly parallel, where scoped windowed functions are not (exactly) the bucketing is parallel, but the order-by are not. But perhaps you mean using a UDTF which can do the "aggregation" in JavaScript, and then emit a single row per bucket.

Comment: as to the performance of a UDTF verse the in-built functions, their is waste in both, but if you don't sort the date, and in the function keep the high watermarks for each tracked value independently, I would guess the UDTF would win in the 5+ values range (completely mad up feeling number) but if this side question was of martial merit, I would total do an experiment on your data. if it's going to run "for hours a day, every day for years" half a days experiment time should pay off nicely.